# Changing PHP code for Yahoo BOSS V1 to BOSS V2

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo-boss-api

I have a solid test page for Yahoo BOSS V1 that I need to make compatible with the V2 code which uses OAuth. Here is the V1 page:

```
<!--###V1 CODE###-->
<html>
<head><title>Yahoo BOSS v2 testing</title></head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<label for="query"> Search </label>
<?php
echo '<input name="query" value="' . $_GET['query'] . '">';
?>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
$search_term = $_GET['query'];
if ($search_term != "") {
 // Build search request.
 $base_url = "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/";
 $vertical = "web/";
 $version = "v1/";
 $search_term = urlencode($search_term);
 $appid = "?appid=" . "your-app-id-here"; // replace with your app-id
 $start = "&start=" . "0";
 $count = "&count=" . "10";
 $request_url = $base_url . $vertical . $version . $search_term . $appid . $start . $count;
 // Send search request.
 $curl_handle = curl_init($request_url);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
 $raw_results = curl_exec($curl_handle);
 curl_close($curl_handle);
 $results_dict = json_decode($raw_results);
 $results = $results_dict->ysearchresponse->resultset_web;
}
else {
$results = array();
}
?>

<!-- #### RESULTS BEGIN ####-->
<div id="results">
<?php
foreach ($results as $result) {
echo '<div class="result">';
echo '<h3 class="title"><a href='.$result->clickurl.'">'.$result->title.'</a></h3>';
echo '<p class="summary">'.$result->abstract.'</p>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>

<?php
// Some code...
//$start = "&start=" . "0";
$start_val = $_GET['start'];
if ($start_val == "") $start_val = 0;
$start = "&start=" . $start_val;
// Some more code...
$count_val = 10;
$count = "&count=" . $count_val;

if ($query != "") {
if ($start_val != 0) {
echo '<a href="?query='.$_GET['query'] . '&start='. (intval($start_val) - intval($count_val))  .'">previous</a>';
echo '<span> | </span>';
}
echo '<a href="?query='.$_GET['query'] . '&start='.(intval($start_val) + intval($count_val)) . '">next</a>';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This V1 code makes sense for the most part to me. I need to integrate the BOSS V2 PHP code into this. But how? Below is the V2 BOSS example code:

```
<!--###V2 CODE###-->
<?php  
require("OAuth.php");  

$cc_key  = "your consumer key here";  
$cc_secret = "your consumer secret here";  
$url = "http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web";  
$args = array();  
$args["q"] = "yahoo";  
$args["format"] = "json";  

$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);  
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url, $args);  
$request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);  
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));  
$ch = curl_init();  
$headers = array($request->to_header());  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
$rsp = curl_exec($ch);  
$results = json_decode($rsp);  
print_r($results);  
?>
```

I think I need to replace $appid in V1 with $cc_key and $cc_secret from V2. But lines 12-22 in V2 have me very confused. What would the code in V1 look like if it used the example code from V2?

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to solve this myself. I would appreciate feedback from someone familiar with PHP.

```
<html>
<head><title>Yahoo BOSS v2 testing</title></head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<label for="query"> Search </label>
<?php
echo '<input name="query" value="' . $_GET['query'] . '">';
?>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php

require("OAuth.php");  

$search_term = $_GET['query'];
 if ($search_term != "") {

 // Build search request.
 $cc_key  = "your consumer key here";  
 $cc_secret = "your consumer secret here";  
 $url = "http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web";  
 $args = array();  
 $args["q"] = "yahoo";  
 $args["format"] = "json";

 // Send search request.
 $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);  
 $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url, $args);  
 $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);  
 $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));  
 $ch = curl_init();  
 $headers = array($request->to_header());  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
 $rsp = curl_exec($ch);  
 $results = json_decode($rsp);  
 print_r($results);
 }
 else {
 $results = array();
}
?>

<!-- #### RESULTS BEGIN ####-->
<div id="results">
 <?php
 foreach ($results as $result) {
   echo '<div class="result">';
   echo '<h3 class="title"><a href='.$result->clickurl.'">'.$result->title.'</a></h3>';
   echo '<p class="summary">'.$result->abstract.'</p>';
   echo '</div>';
 }
 ?>
</div>

<?php
//-//$start = "&start=" . "0";
//$start_val = $_GET['start'];
//if ($start_val == "") $start_val = 0;
// $start = "&start=" . $start_val;
//$count_val = 10;
//$count = "&count=" . $count_val;

//if ($query != "") {
//   if ($start_val != 0) {
//   echo '<a href="?query='.$_GET['query'] . '&start='. (intval($start_val) - intval($count_val))  .'">previous</a>';
//   echo '<span> | </span>';
//   }
//   echo '<a href="?query='.$_GET['query'] . '&start='.(intval($start_val) + intval($count_val)) . '">next</a>';
// }
?>

</body>
</html>
```